# Bash: Creating a second stderr alternative

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that is intended to have an alternative second stderr analogue:

```
exec 3>/dev/tty
echo "STDOUT" >&1
echo "STDERR" >&2
echo "STDDEV" >&3
```

Thus I'd like to filter out each of it's streams differently. It works correctly in the next cases:

1. When I do not filter any stream.

```
$ bash test.bash 
STDOUT
STDERR
STDDEV
```

2. When I suppress stdout

```
$ bash test.bash > /dev/null
STDERR
STDDEV
```

3. When I suppress stderr

```
$ bash test.bash 2> /dev/null
STDOUT
STDDEV
```

Unfortunately, the attempt to suppress the stddev doesn't results in actually suppressing it:

```
$ bash test.bash 3> /dev/null
STDOUT
STDERR
STDDEV
```

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a condition before creating FD3:

```bash
{ >&3; } 2>/dev/null || exec 3>/dev/tty

echo STDOUT >&1
echo STDERR >&2
echo STDDEV >&3
```

`{ >&3; }` evaluates to `true` when FD3 has been defined externally, like in `test.bash 3> /dev/null`

Comment: Thanks a lot, that seems to work like intended. Could you also be kind to elaborate what `2>/dev/null` is supposed to do in the context of the whole first line? It looks like it supposed to mute stderr in some way but at the same time it probably doesn't.

Comment: Muting stderr for the duration of testing whether fd 3 is already open is exactly what it does. You don't want an error printed in that case after all.

Answer (score 1):

When you run `bash test.bash 3> /dev/null` you are redirecting FD 3 in your current shell process. Then, you run test.bash in a subprocess. In the subprocess, you are now redirecting FD 3 again:

```
exec 3>/dev/tty
```

This redirection in the subprocess overrides whatever redirection you had in the parent process.

You need to leave out that line from your test.bash and hope that whatever calls it, defines FD 3 before it calls it.